# Pass Variables to Parent View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which pushes a UIViewController and I need to pass two NSDates and a BOOL from that child view controller back to the table view controller.

How could I do this? Let me know if I am not being clear or you need more explanation.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You should post your specific question.  SO isn't an appropriate place to conduct polls and if you know there are already dups of this question, then you need to state specifically what necessitates a new question.

Comment: I did specify my problem and exactly what i need straight away. I need to pass some variables as I mentioned, two NSDates and a single BOOL from a pushed UIViewController to its parent UITableViewController. I then simply went on to explain that essentially, please don't get tied up in the fact there are lots of these questions about already, so I said 'if' you feel there is a worthy answer already around, let me know you feel thats the right approach (rather than rewriting it) and then I will expand on how I can't get that solution working. Forgive me, I didn't intend for this to be a poll.

Comment: The delegate design pattern is the correct strategy for this case.

Comment: Ok let me change my question seen as people seem to be responding badly to my question.

Comment: May I ask why I am receiving so many down votes?

Comment: The previous form of the question was unfriendly to people trying to read it.  Other down-votes might have come from the fact that the answer to your question is a delegate and you haven't given any real reason why that doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, I guess thats fair, sorry for that. I am trying to implement a delegate as demonstrated by the answer Locke gave me below, however straight away, my (child) view controller doesn't have a delegate property, so how am I supposed to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a delegate is the proper way of passing info from one controller to another.

Generally, what you want to do is to declare a protocol in your `UITableViewController` header, implement it, and then init the `UIViewController` with a delegate.

In a nutshell, your `UITableViewController .h` file should have something like this:

```
@protocol setDateDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setDateOne:(NSDate *)one dateTwo:(NSDate *)two;
@end
```

Then, you ought to implement the above mentioned class doing whatever you want to do with the dates in your `UITableViewController .m` file.

In your `UIViewController`, you could (alternative at the end) define a custom init method:

First, define a delegate property in your .h, and a custom init method, then implement it in your .m with something like this:

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(NSObject *)myDelegate
{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = myDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Next, when you need to pass the dates to your `UITableViewController`, just use 
`[self.delegate setDateOne:one dateTwo:two];`

There are more ways of doing this, including skipping the custom init method and just setting the delegate after you create a `UIViewController`:

```
MyUIViewController *viewController = [[[MyUIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
viewController.delegate = self;
...
```

It's more of a personal preference style.

I've probably messed up the code (and forgotten a few bits) because I'm writing this off the top of my head, but it should be good enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Theres a problem straight away, trying the set the view controllers (the child) delegate isn't happening as it has no delegate property, any reason why this might be?

Comment: There is no inherent delegate for you to use, you have to make one yourself as a property of your child view controller.